# Templavoila extension supports TYPO3 CMS 7.6.4 LTS

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, templavoila

I want to upgrade TYPO3 version from `6.2` to `7.6.4` LTS.
But after upgrade, TYPO3 backend would be destroy,
It throws below templavoila related error

> Warning: require(../../../../typo3/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/typo3/[project_name]/typo3conf/ext/templavoila/mod2/index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../../../../typo3/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/typo3/[project_name]/typo3conf/ext/templavoila/mod2/index.php on line 17

I have searched in below link
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/templavoila
it says that templavoila is compatible until `7.9.99`.

So anyone facing same problem, please reply me.

Comment: Maybe you should manually remove the templavoila extension folder from your typo installation + the database tables of it(save it locally) and then install the newest version via backend. If there are any files within the templavoila folder that you have made changes in, you will replace the new files with the old ones after it is running again. If the error comes up again you know that one of these old files caused the error. 

Little site note: I would suggest you working with Fluid, Templavoila is nearly dead and it`s not sure how long it will be supported in the future.

Comment: TYPO3 Version 7.5 reworked the API for backend modules. TemplaVoila is not yet compatible with this version. TemplaVoila is still not dead as others have claimed it. But you must wait a time for the next version of it.

Comment: A TemplaVoila fork for TYPO3 7 and PHP 7 is currently developed under https://github.com/pluspol-interactive/templavoila .

Answer (score 4):

There is a new Extension "TemplaVoilà Plus" which is compatible with TYPO3 7/8 LTS in the TYPO3 Extension Repository (TER) available. It is the original TemplaVoilà source ported to newer TYPO3 API and extended on some parts and an added Migration part.

- TER: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/templavoilaplus
- Migration Dokumentation:
  https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/templavoilaplus/Migration/Index.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday and found a github repo that fixes the problems with the missing init.php

https://github.com/Calius/templavoila/commit/59d93846a2ea50279d73dac895a541afb27394e2

Unfortunately this does not seem to fix all errors with the latest Typo3 Version (currently 7.6.9). Still getting errors while editing pages in the backend.

No updates for about a year now, broken with the latest Typo3 Version for at least two months (If Franz is correct in the previous post it's been broken for at least 8 months) . TemplaVoila might not be dead, but it's not really useable either.

Comment: I have found a developer who develops templavoila and who needs some payment for his work before he gives you access to his Git repository.

(https://www.templavoila.support/typo3-76)